# On javascript clock, time format need to be 20.03.23 10:42:55 not 2020.03.23 10:42:55

Tags: javascript

Caould anbody please help me, how I can change my javascript code to show year 20 not 2020. I cannot get it write :( 
Thank you in advice. I was trying to add some javascript divide codes but without luck

````
const timedate = () => {
  const currentTime = new Date(new Date().getTime() + diff);
  let hours = currentTime.getHours();
  const minutes = pad(currentTime.getMinutes());
  const seconds = pad(currentTime.getSeconds());

  const d = currentTime.getDate();
  const day = pad(d);
  const month = pad(currentTime.getMonth() + 1);
  const yyyy = currentTime.getFullYear();

/*  let dn = "PM"
  if (hours <= 12) dn = "AM";
  if (hours >= 12) hours -= 12;
  if (hours == 0) hours = 12; */
  hours = pad(hours);
  timeOutput.value = "" +
    yyyy + "." + month + "." + day +
    " " +
    hours + ":" +
    minutes + ":" +
    seconds// + dn;
}
let timeOutput;
let serverTime;
let diff;
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  timeOutput = document.getElementById("timedate");
  serverTime = new Date;// change to new Date("[[:Date:]]"); for example
  diff = new Date().getTime() - serverTime.getTime();
  setInterval(timedate, 1000);
}); ```
````

Answer (score 1):

```js
d = Date.now();
    d = new Date(d);
    d = d.getDate()+'.'+(d.getMonth()+1)+'.'+d.getFullYear()+' '+d.getHours()+':'+d.getMinutes()+':'+d.getSeconds()

    console.log(d);
```